# Add link to image in specific area of image

Tags: c#

I'm creating a image as a signature for Outlook, so im creating a template that my co-workers can edit to their own personal information.

But i want the company site, personal linkedin, and company facebook in the document as links. So when you click on it it sends you to the site (a link usually does that )

This is what the image looks like when i convert it to an image:

[image: Example image]

As you can see in the image you have a couple of thinks that should be filled in by the person using the application. The image is a panel that is converted with this code:

```
     private void ConvertToImageButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(BackgroundPanel.Width, BackgroundPanel.Height);
        BackgroundPanel.DrawToBitmap(bmp, BackgroundPanel.Bounds);
        bmp.Save(@"C:\Users\collin-k\repo\test.png", ImageFormat.Png);
    }
```

**Question: **
How can i add links to the image on a specific place, lets say the place of the website label.

Is this even possible or do you have another idea for a signature that looks like this. The image is a easy way because you can easily edit it.

Comment: Use Photoshop . You can easily embed links in there

Comment: You do realize that a png is not an HTML, right?

Comment: @RajeevKumar Is has to be eddited in a custom c# program, otherwise i have to make signatures for everyone in the company being 300 people

Comment: @Amit What can be considered html thenm?

Comment: You can use the BackgroundPanel's click event to work out a difficult algorithm to check where the user clicked, or use another format, that supports links.

Comment: Either don't use an image and use HTML with text and hyperlinks or use a separate image for each thing you want to be linked and then wrap those images in appropriate anchor tags.

Comment: A png is a file type that (mostly) contains pixel data representing an image. An image has no features such as links, nor does it have anything "smarter" than pixels. HTML is **COMPLETELY DIFFERENT**.

Comment: I think what ypu´re after is called an ImageMap. It´s basically a list of coordinates put onto an image that serve as a link. However creating those lists for 300people within a program is quite difficult, from where should this program know at which location to insert those 300 links?

Comment: You should generate an HTML signature in you program instead of an image.

Comment: @CKY manage the signature with policies and scripts. prefer standard and simple tools over complex custom solutions **not supported natively by ol**. [here](http://www.immense.net/deploying-unified-email-signature-template-outlook/]) is the first example of something similar popped up on google.

Comment: @Franck How can i create an outlook signature that works then, because ive made on and when i send it to a hotmail or gmail account the spacing and stuff get messed up by outlook. Because outlook puts their own custom html in your signtures html. So can you tell me how i can generate a signature from my application

Comment: @Paolo Page doesnt exsist....

Comment: @CKY my bad, a typo in the url, just remove the trailing square bracket

Comment: I know how to mkae one in a html file, but i want it to look like the image in the question and outlook doesnt let me because it puts itsown html in de code